# iPad app recommendation for photo sharing

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, photos, sharing

I recently bought an iPad 2 for my parents, and I'm looking for an app that allows me to share photos (JPEGs) on my Windows PC with them. I imagine myself dropping the images somwhere, and they can see the photos by opening the app. I would like something simple to use that doesn't require sending a link or opening a browser, and that the pictures be private. I would also accept an app that only stores pictures temporarily (they are not meant for long-term storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of is Dropbox: You can just drop (as the name suggest) some photos in a folder on your PC or Mac (or another mobile device) and they'll automatically be synchronized with the folders and apps on your other devices.

https://www.dropbox.com

Comment: Agreed, Dropbox would work well for this. You could either use the same account on the iPad and PC (if photo sharing is all you'd use Dropbox for), or create separate accounts and a shared folder.